# Como gerar o código EAD para PAF-ECF em C#, conforme ATO COTEPE 23/15?

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber se alguém poderia auxiliar na geração do código EAD em C# para registro tipo Rxx conforme documentação do Ato Cotepe 23/15.
Veja o link https://www.confaz.fazenda.gov.br/legislacao/atos/atos_cotepe/2015/ato-cotepe-icms-23-15, assunto tratado no requisito XXXI do anexo I.
A documentação explica superficialmente como fazer o cálculo e não encontrei assuntos relacionados que possam esclarecer essa dúvida.
Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais simples de assinar os arquivos do PAF-ECF é com os componentes do Projeto ACBr. Ele possui componentes dedicados ao PAF que agilizam e muito o desenvolvimento de qualquer sistema.

Para não usar um Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V e dar crédito a quem merece acesse o post: [Assinatura de Arquivos PAF](http://www.projetoacbr.com.br/forum/topic/7432-assinatura-de-arquivos-paf/)

Site do projeto [ACBrFramework](http://acbrframework.sourceforge.net/)

PS: Esse projeto possui suporte a varias outras linguagens como Java, C/C++, FoxPro, Clipper, Harbour. Para delphi acesse [Delphi](http://www.projetoacbr.com.br/forum/)